# Copy contents of non null terminated char array into another char array

Tags: c, arrays, strcpy

I have an array of structs, each struct has a char array and an int.

```
typedef struct {
    int id; //Each struct has an id
    char input[80]; //Each struct has a char array
    } inpstruct;

inpstruct history[10]; //Array of structs is created
```

I have another char array that contains the user's input

```
char inputBuffer[80];
```

The user enters a word followed by the `\n` character. For example, `inputBuffer` will contain 3 chars: `'l'` `'s'` `'\n'`.

I want to copy all the chars in `inputBuffer` into `history[index].input`

I have tried using:

```
strcpy(history[index].input, inputBuffer);
```

But since `inputBuffer` is not null terminated it does not work. How can I copy all the chars from `inputBuffer` into `history[index].input` ?

Comment: `length = read(STDIN_FILENO, inputBuffer, 80);`

Comment: define `it does not work`

Comment: `strcpy` is, you guessed it, for c-style 0-terminated strings. You want to copy raw memory, thus use `memcpy`.

Comment: using `memcpy(history[index].input, inputBuffer, sizeof inputBuffer);` I get the error 'memcpy' call operates on objects of type 'char' while the size is based on a different type 'char *'

Comment: Seems you don't pass the array to `sizeof`, but a pointer to its contents. Probably due to array-decay in a function-call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to memcpy

```
memcpy(history[index].input, inputBuffer, sizeof(inputBuffer)*sizeof(inputBuffer[0]));
```

Comment: I get the warning `warning: sizeof on array function parameter will return size of 'char *' instead of 'char []'` and then the error `malloc: *** error for object 0x10ae0d074: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

Comment: You need to show more of your code.  The `sizeof` operator should would exactly as I showed. If however, the elements are pointers being passed into a function, then `sizeof` will NOT work (which is what your error message suggests), and you will have to hard code the size.  FYI -- the malloc error has nothing todo with the code you shared, and suggests you are trying to free a pointer that was not previously allocated by `malloc()`.

Comment: Yes inputBuffer is being passed into a void method where the memcpy is being done. I also hard coded the size to be 80 but i still get the malloc error when I run it

Comment: As I said the malloc error is another kettle of fish. Your code is calling `free()` with memory that was not previously allocated by `malloc()`. Run debugger to find the exact place in your code where this is happening and fix.