# How to copy a non null terminated string to dynamic memory

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, memcpy, delete-operator, freeze

First off, this is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220194/copy-contents-of-non-null-terminated-char-array-into-another-char-array). My question is how to do it with dynamic memory. The reason this is distinct is because my `delete[]` is hanging.

So, here's what I have:

```
class PacketStrRet {
    public:
    PacketStrRet(char p_data[], int p_len) : len(p_len) {
        data = new char[p_len];
        memcpy(data, p_data, p_len * sizeof(char));
    }

    ~PacketStrRet() { 
        delete[] data; 
        data = nullptr;
    }

    char* data;
    int len;
};
```

And yes, I'm aware that my code is not using the best practices. I'll clean it up later.

The problem I'm having is in the DTOR. That delete is hanging forever. The data being passed in to the CTOR is *not* dynamic memory, so I need to make it dynamic so things don't go out of scope. `p_len` holds the correct amount of data, so there's no problem there.

From what I've read, `memcpy` seems to be the most likely culprit here. So how do I copy a string that is not null-terminated to dynamic memory, and then still be able to delete it later?

Thanks.

Comment: This also looks like a rule-of-three violation.

Comment: @KerrekSB, can you put that into an answer?

Comment: That looks ok. You could remove the *sizeof(char) in the memcpy as long as you don't have a weird platform or add it also to the `new` invocation, but that shouldn't make a difference. I guess the error is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the delete, only everything that comes before and even that would be ok if there didn't occur any problems.

```
class PacketStrRet {
    // Use RAII
    std::unique_ptr<char> data; // I own this data and will destroy it.
    // now the parent class is also only movable, use shared_ptr if you can't live with that.
    int len;

    public:
    PacketStrRet(
        // <RED ALERT>
        char p_data[], int p_len // user can lie to us.
        // </RED ALERT>
        ) try : // function try block, se 1)
          len(p_len), data(new char[p_len]) {
        memcpy(data, p_data.get(), p_len * sizeof(char));
    } catch(const std::exception& e) {
      std::cerr << "arg=" << arg << " failed: " << e.what() << '\n';
    }

    ~PacketStrRet() { 
        // unique_ptr takes care of memory management and garbage collection.
    }   
    // access functions
};
```

Now the possible errors you could make to blow the code up.

You could have copied the object, essentially making two owning raw pointers to the same data. This would blow up at delete, you coudl use memory-sanitizer / valgrind to confirm this happens. Use smart pointers to save you the trouble, the unique pointer *should* cause a compiler error if you tried to copy, unless you memcpy the entire structure ignoring the copy/assignment constructors.

You could give the wrong len to the constructor, what is the source of the data and len? Valgrind / memory-sanitizer can save you.

The memory corruption could happen in a totally different place. Valgrind / memory-sanitizer can save you.

In case valgrind mem-san are too much, you can try to make a check for double delete, if you make a counter in c'tor and d'tor and if it ever goes to negative you have your error.

In this class your at least missing a copy constructor. Check up on rule of 3, 5, 7 and 0 (zero) to find out how many you need.

1) http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block

Answer (score -1):

Try to use std:: copy(). It will be like this: 
`std::copy(p_data, p_data + p_len, data).`

Comment: How is this any different than `memcpy`, aside from a lot more overhead?

Comment: @David -- `std::copy` doesn't have "a lot more overhead".